# How do I fix this to deploy Rails app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Everything is working fine when I run 'heroku local'!

But, when I run 'heroku open', it does not work:

> "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped
>   the address or the page may have moved. If you are the application
>   owner check the logs for more information."

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
ruby '2.2.1'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'puma'
gem 'foreman'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

This is the Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -e  -p 5000 -S ~/puma -C config/puma.rb
```

And this is the file logs:

```
2015-05-20T12:38:42.297654+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 183.81.86.77 at 2015-05-20 12:38:42 +0000
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392427+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392433+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392437+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392445+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392435+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392452+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392456+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392439+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392440+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392458+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392459+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392461+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392462+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392463+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:82:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392442+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392443+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392466+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392467+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392455+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392453+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392450+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392468+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392470+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392472+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392464+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
2015-05-20T12:38:42.392471+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-20T12:38:42.777619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bachvanngoc.herokuapp.com request_id=29570c12-9b74-4b70-b109-7365acb4938e fwd="183.81.86.77" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143
2015-05-20T12:38:41.882707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.37.1 update available.
```

Comment: Check the logs by running `heroku logs`; will give an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: Based on the console/log output, you did not define a base route (i.e., `root to: 'some_controller#some_action'`) in your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to be a deployment issue but a routing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a deployment issue

From your Heroku logs it seems that you have not defined a route to handle the root path.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
```

If you look at your `config/routes.rb` file you need to define a controller/action to handle that path.

Something like:

```
root to: "acontroller#anaction"
```

or

```
get "/" => "acontroller#anaction"
```

Rails during development serves a default page at the root path. If you run the rails app in production this default page will not be shown. You can check this locally by doing `rails server -e production` and you'll notice that you don't get that same home page but the same page that you get in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You should to be in the project path, and run:

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

and,

```
heroku run db:migrate
```

Also run

```
heroku --help
```

For more information.

Comment: Thanks, i run this before. I fixed the error by routing root.:))

Comment: @NeverSmile Why would you choose this answer if it's not the one that solved your problem..

Comment: :)) i choose both of them, but stackoverflow only choose after one.